# Is it possible to add malayalam language to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Can anybody say is it possible to add malayalam language to CKEditor? I just want the features of ckeditor for creating a dynamic website using malayalam language.

Comment: pattum :D check this link : http://www.vishalon.net/PramukhIME/CKEditorPlugin.aspx

Comment: How can I add the buttons mentioned below? 


In the init function for TinyMCE (in the Webpage), add "pramukhime" in a plugin list and 
      add "pramukhime", "pramukhimeclick", "pramukhimeconvert" and "pramukhimehelp" button for 
   language dropdown list, type using mouse, convert to another language and help buttons respectively

Comment: wondering the same ?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is [available in Malay](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/uilanguages.html) and you can [follow or even contribute](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/ckeditor/language/ms/) to the translation process. Simply run editor like that:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    language: 'ms'
});
```

Or update [config.language](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-language) in your configuration file.

Comment: For your information, Malay and Malayalam are entirely different languages.